# How to Select all text in VBS?

Tags: windows, select, text, vbscript

I know this should be simple but I cant get it to work. 
I have
    WshShell.Sendkeys "^{X}" working for copying/cutting text
    WshShell.Sendkeys "^{V}" working for pasting text but
    WshShell.Sendkeys "^{A}" does not work to select text. Im confused.

Anyone got tips? Thanks.
If it helps, the text is being copied out of notepad and into an adobe pdf text field. 
Thanks!

Comment: Please follow this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Answer (score 2):

Use this...

```
WshShell.SendKeys "^{a}"
```

Comment: Thank you! That has seamed to work. Should I change my other commands to lower case as well? How come this one is the only one that does not work so far as capital? I also have TAB as one of the commands.  Should I make that lower case?

Comment: Try this links : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx ; http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html